# node - Converting to JSON fails, but can print in console

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm attempting to convert an array to JSON to be sent to a client. Here is what the data looks like in console:

```
[ NL: [ true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true ],                                                                                        
LU: [ true,                                                                                                                                                            
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
false,                                                                                                                                                               
false,                                                                                                                                                               
false ],                                                                                                                                                             
SE: [ false, false, false ] ]
```

However when I run this (res being an express.js socket):

```
console.log(st.bot.serverStatus);
res.send(JSON.stringify(st.bot.serverStatus));
```

I get the output in console like expected, but I get `[]` from the web browser. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am unable to change the format of the elements, they are generated by this method:

```
        if(st.bot.serverStatus[tmp.country] !== undefined) {
            st.bot.serverStatus[tmp.country][st.bot.serverStatus[tmp.country].length] = alive;
        } else {
            st.bot.serverStatus[tmp.country] = [ alive ];
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the output you get from the server?

Comment: How are you initializing `st.bot.serverStatus`  ?

Comment: st.bot.serverStatus = [];

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid syntax at `SE:` and `LE:` since it is an array and not an object.  Change the outermost `[]` to `{}` or change `:` to `,`

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({ NL: [ true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true ],                                                                                        
LU: [ true,                                                                                                                                                            
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
false,                                                                                                                                                               
false,                                                                                                                                                               
false ],                                                                                                                                                             
SE: [ false, false, false ] } ));
```

Or:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([{ NL: [ true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true ]},                                                                                        
{LU: [ true,                                                                                                                                                            
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
true,                                                                                                                                                                
false,                                                                                                                                                               
false,                                                                                                                                                               
false ]},                                                                                                                                                             
{SE: [ false, false, false ] }] ));
```

Your JSON format is incorrect.

Use something like

[jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)

or

[jsoneditoronline.org](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

To validate your JSONs